# Checking if attribute exits if only then select element

Tags: xpath

My xpath works file when there is an attribute name test.

```
<A>
  <B test="Added">
     <C>test</C>
  </B>
</A>
```

XPATH

```
//B[@test !='Deleted']/C/text()
```

But the same XPATH does not work when there is no attribute name test.

```
<A>
  <B>
     <C>test</C>
  </B>
</A>
```

XPATH

```
//B[@test!='Deleted']/C/text()
```

What should I do to make it work even if there is no attribute name test.

Comment: Did you mean *when there is no attribute name **clientoffset*** ?

Comment: See my answer for XPath that will work in both cases..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `not(@test ='Deleted')` instead :

```
//B[not(@test ='Deleted')]/C/text()
```

This XPath matches `B` elements where `test` attribute doesn't equal `'Deleted'`, including the case when attribute `test` is not present.

---

Demo: [`xpathtester`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/522a9476ef24875912361b2dba7625c8), [`xpatheval`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/c6fl89O_V)

**XML:**

```
<root>
<A>
  <B test="Added">
     <C>test</C>
  </B>
</A>
<A>
  <B>
     <C>test</C>
  </B>
</A>
</root>
```

**output :**

```
test
test
```